# Create Neo4j relationship dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I want to create a number of relationships between existing nodes in NEO4j. The relationships are not known until compile time or run time so I would to use a variable for the [rel:"RELATIONSHIP_TO] part of the query. I have seen a similar question [Creating Neo4j Relationships in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928343/creating-neo4j-relationships-in-java) on SO that uses:

```
  RelationshipType relType = DynamicRelationshipType.withName(rel);
  graphDb.createNode().createRelationshipTo(graphDb.createNode(), relType);
```

However that was two years ago and the doc now says **DynamicRelationshipType** is deprecated. The documentation  also spoke to using Java "enums" with **RelationshipType** which I don't believe will work in my case. I want to do this:

```
node1.createRelationshipTo(node2,relType)
```

where relType is a variable. How can I do this? Any help is appreciated. My project is on Nodejs and Javascript with the latest Neo4jDB.

**ADDITIONALLY** I would also like to know how to use a variable for the "key" in the property assignment for both the relationships and the nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `create.relationship` procedure from [`apoc`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data):

```
CALL apoc.create.relationship(person1,'KNOWS',{key:value,…​}, person2)
```

**Upd**:

```
MERGE (person1:Person {name:1})
MERGE (person2:Person {name:2})
WITH 'KNOWS' as relType, person1, person2
CALL apoc.create.relationship(person1, relType, null, person2) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

Comment: I cannot find any documentation that would allow me to use a variable "reltype" for "KNOWS". That is my question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Apparently I am not getting my question across properly. The WITH 'KNOWS' still require me to know what the relType is ahead of time. Can I do something like this: **WITH rel as relType** where rel is a variable with any value I get from a file.